# PHP parsing sql result set

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to parse an SQL result set and I'm running into multiple issues.

```
        foreach ( $rows as $key => $row ) {
            die(print(gettype( $row )));  // DIE 1
            if ( is_array( $row ) ) {
                foreach ( (array)$row as $k => $r ) {
                    die(print_r($r));     // DIE 2
                    if ( !in_array( $r['proposal'], $proposals ) ) {
                        array_push( $proposals, $r['proposal'] );
                    }
                    if ( !in_array( $r['question'], $scorequestions ) && $r['type'] == 'score' ) {
                        array_push( $scorequestions, $r['question'] );
                    }
                    if ( !in_array( $r['question'], $recommendquestions ) && $r['type'] == 'recommend' ) {
                        array_push( $recommendquestions, $r['question'] );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My $rows is: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWdgt.jpg)

```
+----------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+------+
| question | title  | campaign | type      | proposal | avg     | recommend | conditional | cnt  |
+----------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+------+
|      101 | Title1 |      104 | score     |       38 |  6.6667 |         0 |           0 |    3 |
|      101 | Title2 |      104 | score     |       39 |  9.6667 |         0 |           0 |    3 |
|      101 | Title3 |      104 | score     |       40 |  8.0000 |         0 |           0 |    2 |
|      101 | Title4 |      104 | score     |       41 |  3.0000 |         0 |           1 |    2 |
|      101 | Title5 |      104 | score     |       42 |  9.0000 |         0 |           0 |    1 |
|      101 | Title6 |      104 | score     |       43 |  9.0000 |         0 |           0 |    1 |
|      101 | Title7 |      104 | score     |       44 |  7.6667 |         0 |           0 |    3 |
```

$rows is an SQL result set. DIE 1 print tells me $row is an array, YET the is_array() function thinks it's not an array.

If I skip that if loop (comment it out) and run the inner foreach loop, DIE 2 gives me:

```
Array ( [question] => 105 [campaign] => 104 [type] => recommend [proposal] => 42 [avg] => -1.0000 [recommend] => 1 [conditional] => 1 [cnt] => 1 [title] => Title5 [amount] => 300 [theme] => offline ) 1
```

But then I get an illegal string offset error on $r['proposal']. Not sure where I'm going wrong. I have read through multiple SO threads before posting this.

Comment: Hi @u_mulder A little more explanation please? What should I fix and where?

Comment: If I write it just as:
    foreach( $row as $k => $r )
then I get:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: How do you obtain the $rows variable? Could you post a sample with that?

Comment: It comes from the database. Doing a die on it gives me: http://i.imgur.com/YUpZvBx.png (ugly, I know)

Comment: I see the problem: $rows is an object that has a 'rows' field. You need to iterate on $rows->rows in the outer form. Also with this in mind, you might change the $rows variable to something like $result.

Comment: (FYI - if you copy/paste from the page source instead of as rendered in the browser, the `print_r()` output will retain all linebreaks and indentation for readability)

Comment: Oh thanks @Cristik! Let me try that. And thanks for the tip @Michael Berkowski, will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: I still have the second problem. Illegal string offset in $r['proposal']

Comment: Oh no. I was making a silly mistake. Thanks everyone! @Cristik, if you'd like to add that formally as an answer, I'd be able to mark it as accepted. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Ok, will post it as an answer, but my answer will not make sense for other readers if you don't also post the code where you get the results from the db, could you also add that to the code snippet from the question?

Comment: Or add the imur.com link, I think that would suffice too.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: Did the guy with the "you should remove the (array) conversion)" deleted its comment, or am I simply not seeing them :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating directly over $rows, while $rows is an object that has a $rows members that holds the actual data. So you should iterate over $rows->rows in the outer loop.